# Using a form to run javascript method

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to run a JS method with a custom text variable as a parameter. I need to be able to write some text in a form, and then send that value to the method to execute it. I'm not sure why it's not working - it seems to be receiving the value of the VALUE as "" or blank. How would I go about doing this?

```
    <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
Choose a Place: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" id = "place"><P>
</FORM>

<button type="button" onclick="buttonGenerator()">Generate Postcard</button>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('place').value;
    function buttonGenerator(){
        generate(x);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x variable is being set when the script first runs (when the page is loading). You want to avoid setting it until the button is clicked. Simply move it into the function and you should be set:

```
function buttonGenerator(){
    var x = document.getElementById('place').value;
    generate(x);
}
```